# starting a service from dialog box in android

Tags: android, android-service, android-dialog

I'm trying to start a background service from a pop-up dialog and it's just doesn't work for me

this is the code for opening the dialog box:

```
reportWrongLang.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            ReportWrongLangDialog Dialog = new ReportWrongLangDialog(imageInfo.getParam("imageId")[0], getApplicationContext());
            Dialog.show(fm, "are_you_sure_dialog");
        }
```

in the ReportWrongLangDialog i am saving the appContext, and the imageId

and in the dialog when pressing the report button I want to start the background service that will report about the image

the code for the onClick

```
report.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            System.out.println("got imageid: " + imageId);
            Intent intent = new Intent(appContext, ReportImageService.class);
            intent.putExtra("ReportType", "IMAGE_REPORT");
            intent.putExtra("ImageID", imageId);
            intent.putExtra("Extra", "2");
            appContext.startService(intent);
            System.out.println("after service start");
        }
    });
```

where ReportImageService.class is the service that I want to start.
when i'm pressing the report button nothing happens..

what can be the problem? I can only assume that there is some problem with the applicationContext

Comment: Is the on click function never being called, or is the startCommand/onCreate of the service never being called?  And if the second, how did you determine this?

Comment: the onClick function is called - I can see that by syso messages

the start command never happens:
    public ReportImageService() {
  super("reportimageservice");
  System.out.println("in report service constractor");
 }

 @Override
 protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
  System.out.println("in report service");
}

no syso at any time

Comment: Did you forget to declare your service in your manifest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem with my app.
The solution that worked for me was:
instead of passing your context and use it later (with getContextApplication() method), there is another way to do it, pass:

> YourActivityName.this

as your context, and then call your startService() method from this object.